# How do I realize a Database based on user form input?

Tags: list, managed-metadata, form, user-accounts

Hello everyone I am new to sharepoint.

Since I dont know much about it yet, I would be thankful if you can drop some hints and key words for my problem since i dont know where to start on this.

Problem: I need a sharepoint where a user can input his data (picture, name, department, ...) into some kind of a template so the input type is the same for every employee. Ideally the data has to be stored on the sharepoint as well in some kind of list.

A second group of users can then look at these profiles and select one to become there sponsor (only 1-1 connection). After this the sponsor has to be manually or automatically disabled.

Do you have hints how I can realize this? Or can you tell me which elements I can use for this?

Also some good user guides would be helpfull if you have good ones.

Kind regards and thank you for any help

Comment: could you kindly explain what exactly you want your application to do?

Comment: @jayantkhushalani there have to be 3 usergroups. Owner, sponsors and employees. New employees can access the sharepoint and chose a sponsor. The task of this sponsor is to help the new employee to find their way into the company and to give them a Contact Person if they have problems or concerns. The sponsors are also employees from the company who want to be in this role. The sponsors should be able to give some information about themselfs in a profile(department, hobbies...). The new employees can search for a sponsor based on a list of departments.

Comment: @jayantkhushalani If they chose a sponsor they get marked as occupied and cant be taken as sponsor until he decides to be free again and they get a notification email that they got chosen as a sponsor

Comment: So let us say you have a sharepoint list storing the list of sponsors along with their basic information  like department and hobbies which is filled up by each sponsor. 
Now, the new employees can go to this list and look through the sponsors which will help them identify which sponsor they should choose

Comment: now after that the selecting of sponsor would take some logic which has to be thought through and i cannot comment on it as of now. but you can start building up the share point list with different sponsor details.